# How frequently are duplicates merged?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

[Some of us believe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52530/are-duplicates-creating-broken-windows) that the addition of many **exact** duplicate questions by new users is lowering the quality of SO. [It has been said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52555/170084) that the answer to this problem is for [high-rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40346/allow-high-rep-users-to-migrate-answers-from-one-question-to-another) to *merge* those duplicate questions together. Apparently, [merged questions have a footer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53322/closed-then-merged-question-missing-merged-to-footer) saying they were merged. I do not recall ever seeing one of those merge footers, or any other evidence of questions being merged. It *seems* that [questions are not being merged.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118379/why-are-duplicates-not-being-merged)

So, just how common is merging of questions? What fraction of duplicates are merged?

If the answer to that question is "not many", should we conclude that merging is **not** a solution to the problem of duplicates?

Comment: Merge should be used when both duplicate questions each have valuable answers, and the canonical question would benefit from having the additional answers from the other question.  If it wouldn't, or there aren't additional answers, then a merge is not appropriate.  Also, merges can only be performed by moderators.

Comment: I'm figuring that since the information is available even if the questions are not merged, merges do not get high priority over all the other tasks that moderators perform to prevent or undo *substantial* harm to the site. I mean, unmerged duplicates are not ideal, but they are not terrible either.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I know. But it seems that questions that *ought* to be merged and *not actually* being merged.

Comment: @Raedwald If you have examples of questions that should be merged and aren't, post them. It's fairly rare that questions actually should be merged.

Comment: @Raedwald I did not go study all of the meta discussions, but can you point out a few examples here of questions that ought to be merged, and why?

Answer (score 5):

As a moderator, I typically only merge questions when they've been asked independently by the same user on multiple sites, and one of them gets migrated to my site. There is no point in keeping around two identical questions by the same user.

I'm not sure exactly how more duplicates degrades the quality of SO - ideally a question is closed as a duplicate before it has a lot of quality answers of its own, although I concede that that is not always the case. In either case, similar questions asked differently can help search efforts, and the user always does have a path to the best answer to the same question (even though it can take a few more clicks).

I actually struggle with this for the tags I frequent (SQL Server) - there are a lot of duplicate questions about certain techniques or features, but the duplicate target doesn't always have the best answer, nor does it always include the best answer for the *current version* of the software. When I see something proposed to be closed as a duplicate, I always check the target, and make sure (a) that the answer(s) there actually answer the question, and (b) that the version(s) involved in the new question would still make best use of the answer in the old question. Sometimes a duplicate can look like an exact duplicate, but the asker is on a newer version of SQL Server than the best answer for older versions, and would be better off with their own answer using the new technique that wasn't possible in the older version (and for a question from 2009 with 800 up-votes on the accepted answer, a better answer for the new version will be lost in the chafe at the bottom). I don't think these are merge candidates either.