# Why was the C# 2.0 tag removed from my question?

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a question (question has been deleted for reasons unrelated to this question) about some code of mine. Nothing in the question was specific to C# 2.0 but that is the version I am developing in. The C# 2.0 tag says "For issues relating to development with C#, version 2.0." and that is what I am doing.

Should I only use this tag if the question I am asking relates to features only present in 2.0? I have been using it mainly as an indicator that answers must be limited to features present in 2.0 (so and answer that uses LINQ for example would be unacceptable), have I been using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I agree with you that the C#-2.0 tag was appropriate.  You are limited to C#-2.0 development, and tagging it C# would leave you open to answers that use features from later versions.

Whenever you are working on the non-current version of a language and are unable to change versions, tagging it with the language version is helpful to me.

Comment: @Fr33dan sanitized

Answer (score 19):

> Should I only use this tag if the question I am asking relates to features only present in 2.0?

Yes. The version-specific tags are for questions concerning issues that are *unique* to that version.

If you just want to tell people what version you're using, you would include that information in the body of the question. Not everything belongs in the tags. You're probably also compiling it on the Windows operating system, but you wouldn't tag it [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows). It is not relevant to the question.

> I have been using it mainly as an indicator that answers must be limited to features present in 2.0 (so and answer that uses LINQ for example would be unacceptable)

No, this would be a perfectly valid usage. But you shouldn't expect that to be clear *just* from the tag. You need to articulate these caveats in the question body.

Especially considering how many people misuse version-specific tags. Editors see this "anti-pattern" and their finger itches to remove them. If there's nothing in the question that indicates they *belong* there and you know what you're doing, they will give in to their urges.

> The C# 2.0 tag says "For issues relating to development with C#, version 2.0." and that is what I am doing.

Yeah, it does. That's too vague. [Fixed that for you](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23-2.0/info).

Comment: This answer introduces a possible issue. What if I do not know that the best answer uses a feature that is not present in 2.0? Say I asked "How do I search an array?" then someone answers with a LINQ answer. Do I edit my question to say that I need a 2.0 answer and add the tag or ask a new question with the the tag now knowing that I have an issue unique to 2.0?

Comment: I don't understand the issue. If you *know* that you cannot target a newer version of the framework, you include this constraint in the question from the very beginning. THen people won't answer with LINQ. Or they might, but for the benefit of others who aren't operating under the same unusual constraints. You are free to ignore their answer.

Comment: You said in this answer that using the tag to indicate that I need a solution that is limited to 2.0 is a valid use of the tag, but since I will not know if possible answers need to be limited I would never get to use it in that context unless I already know there is a solution exclusive to later versions. This will result in questions that belong in that tag for having answers unique to 2.0 (as users have limited their response because 2.0 is mentioned in the text) not ending up where they should be.

Comment: So if there is an answer to a question that uses later features, removing the tag makes that an unhelpful answer.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be clear *just* from the tag that C#3.5 features are not appropriate?

Comment: This is opposite from common practice in the `sql-server` tags. There the consensus generally seems to be that the OP should tag with the version they are specifically using rather than just stick this information in the text of the question somewhere. As an answerer I much prefer seeing this information in a consistent place  too.

Comment: Isn't this a bit contradictive with the fact that we explicitly tell people not to put the language into the title (or question) but use tags for it? This may be a bit reductio ad absurdum, but theoretically we could apply the same argument to the `c#` tag as well. Also in general (there are definitely exceptions!) I'd say it's impossible to know if a problem/solution is specific to one version of the language or not before you know the solution - so that'd be a bit clairvoyant.

Comment: 100% agreed with @Martin. I've lost count of the number of questions I've answered in, say, 2013, where I assumed the OP was on at least SQL Server 2008 (and in some cases even 2005), and this is not the case, and I ended up expending a lot of effort for nothing, because the solution doesn't work on the version they're using (and it's fair to usually make an assumption that they're on something relatively modern). The version tag is a much more appropriate place to determine exact or minimum version than parsing the entire question, sorry.

Comment: @podiluska see [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251188/61305) for my thoughts on that.

Comment: I'm confused on *what* exactly all the commenters (and downvoters) are disagreeing with. I said that the version-specific tags should be used *only* if the question is unique to that version. **If you have a constraint that you must use only that version, then you have an issue unique to that specific version and can/should use the tag.** My point was merely that you shouldn't add tags just to describe your environment when they are not relevant. *Normally*, it doesn't matter if you are using Mono or .NET. If it does, use the tag. Otherwise, if you still want to mention it, put it in the body.

Comment: @yakk The reason it isn't clear from the tag alone is because of how many people misuse version-specific tags. Moreover, there's nothing wrong with duplicating information. A *full* explanation should go in the question body. Always. It doesn't matter if it's already in the title or already in the tags. I shouldn't have to do the detective work myself if I'm going to answer the question. I don't know what Martin and Aaron are talking about, I always read the question first before I answer it.

Comment: Cody, **specific** or **only** version isn't the only problem. **Min** and **max** version can also be very important in a lot of cases, depending on context. I find the version-specific tags *very* useful when thinking about a potential answer, because it immediately tells me what approaches may (not) be possible. That is ***WAY BETTER*** for me to see in a tag than to parse the entire question hoping they may have mentioned it. So my main disagreement is with your suggestion to mention it in the question, where it is hard to find, and where the OP may not know it matters in the first place.

Comment: When I see a specific version mentioned in the body text, I add it as a tag, so that other potential answerers (like Martin) can find it more easily. If I *don't* see a specific version in the question, I ask the OP for one, because in a lot of cases the answer *depends* on the version. When they provide one (and they always do, they just didn't know to offer this voluntarily), it's usually in a comment, and I update the question by changing the tag (not version-tag-stuffing the title or the body).

Comment: You do whatever you feel is appropriate for the C# tags (though I'm sure some of what I'm saying is relevant there too). As a site-wide policy, though, I couldn't disagree more with what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Aaron Okay, I understand your objection. I guess I'm agreeing with you that if the version is relevant, it should be represented in the tags. I just think it should *also* be in the body. And if it *isn't* important, leave it off the tags but still put it in the body. What I don't understand is "min" and "max" version. How do you indicate that? Do you put one tag for the min version and one tag for the max version?

Comment: Sure, often if someone needs a solution that works in 2005 and 2008, they'll tag both. The problem is usually that the OP doesn't realize the version may be relevant, so we're often pulling teeth for this info. By definition this is something the answerers know but the askers rarely do.

Comment: @Voo: A lot of people misunderstand that guidance.  You aren't supposed to use the title or question body as a keyword list, e.g. we often see people title their question as "Ambiguous overload (C++) (templates) (variadic functions)".  That's not appropriate.  Listing germane information in the question title and body, even if it is also listed in the tags, is completely appropriate, and always has been.  No thanks to a few editors who keep trying to remove it.

Comment: @voo (continued) Keyword lists in titles should preferably be changed into meaningful phrases, e.g. "Why does my C++ compiler complain about ambiguous overload only when I add a variadic version?", not simply removed.

Comment: Disagree with this, we have a rule to use tags instead of putting stuff like this in the title, I think its fine if this data is not in the body as well.

Comment: My mind is still blown about how many people "disagree" with this answer because they believe it to be advocating tags in titles. I've read it several times, I still don't see that. I am profoundly against that, I certainly don't know how I am giving impressions otherwise. Maybe I should just delete the answer, it seems to be confusing too many people. I also *cannot* understand why people object to information being provided in the body of the question. No one said *not* to use the tag. I just said it *also* should be in the body. That's where I would look for it. I use tags only for sorting.