# Converting version-specific question to version-agnostic

Tags: discussion, old-questions

When there is popular question marked with specific version (i.e C#, C#-2.0) but answers already cover multiple versions should anything be done about version tag and possibly question/answers?

I think removing version tag and commenting/editing to highlight version specific variants is the approach to take.

Alternatives:

- Do nothing - may confuse people looking for the answer using other/latest version
- Keep tags, add comments/edit question to specify that solutions for any versions are welcome, with one preferable.
- Create new canonical question covering all versions (as wiki, also still would feel like seems pure rep-farming) and duplicate.
- Remove tag, Provide new answer covering all versions (feels low value as it will not show up before exiting once, and likely will not be much better anyway).

Concerns and similar questions:

- people may not like removal of version-specific tag [Why was the C# 2.0 tag removed from my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256723/why-was-the-c-2-0-tag-removed-from-my-question?rq=1)
- Adding new version specific answer to non-version specific question is reasonable practice covered in many questions like [Good question, old version-dependent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer).

I don't see any specific recommendation in [What are the guidelines for using version-specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags).

This post prompted the question: [C# List<> Sort by x then y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289010/c-sharp-list-sort-by-x-then-y)

Comment: I was not thrilled with that edit, it was not accurate.  The OP also **very** specifically asked for a 2.0 solution at the time he asked it.  The point was not *how* it was done, the point was that *why* it was done that way.  Both ways were already demonstrated in the question after the version demand was edited out of the question by others, the Linqy way has double the votes even though it didn't explain the why, good enough for everybody.

Comment: @HansPassant would you mind to summarize your suggestion as an answer? Based on your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/289040/4) it looks like you recommend not to touch answers (fair point), but what about keeping/removing version tag and edits in question?

Comment: @HansPassant downvote all the answers!