# How to deal with version specific questions where the same answer applies to a later version too?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, versions

The issue that led to the question [Where is Create Unit Test in VS **2017**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876897/where-is-create-unit-test-in-vs-2017) is still occurring in Visual Studio 2019.

The feature in question should be added to VS2019 fairly soon and the question doesn't apply to versions of VS prior to VS2017, so I don't think [converting the question to a version-agnostic question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272825/converting-version-specific-question-to-version-agnostic) is appropriate?

I can think of a few possible approaches:

1. Edit the question title to 'VS2017/VS2019', and add a line in the question to say 'This same question also applies to VS2019' and tag it for VS2019 too.
2. Ask a new question with basically the same question and then close it as a duplicate of the first one.
3. Ask a new question and answer it with a link to the original one.

Approach 1 seems the cleanest in a way, but I'm not sure what the preferred approach is?

Comment: That question is my first result when searching google for "Where is Create Unit Test in VS 2019?"... I'm not convinced that anything at all needs to be done.

Comment: @TinyGiant, sorry, yes should have had do nothing as option 4!  Is relying on Google to sort this out generally OK, or is the idea to make SO answers as accurately self contained as possible without needing Google to make the associations?  (I'm thinking of the unlikely possibility of Google no longer existing, or the more possible scenario of data scientists wanting to, say, compare the number of issues from VS2017 compared to those from VS2019)

Comment: If the version isn't relevant to the question, just remove it. You can remove information irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @Braiam versions are always relevant to the question, regressions are common in IDEs and usually every version of an IDE has a few different solutions(especially in the case of visual studio that seemingly does complete rewrites of different modules every couple of years). removing versioning makes the question complete useless when it's marked as solved and the issue happens again a while later and everyone marks the questions as a duplicate. you end up with giant lists of answers with people saying try this and try that

Comment: imo as per my anecdotal data of searching for solutions to issues - versioning should be even more strict than just 2017 vs 2019 etc since VS comes out with tons of bug fix releases(that not all corporate users can upgrade to immediately and they look for fixes)

Comment: I'd go for option 2 if anything at all. The Q you link is a well formulated one, with an extensive answer. Asking a new Q and dupe(hamering/voting) creates that extra exposure and links things together.

Comment: @kkarakk please, those are bugs. Those aren't questions. Practical questions are timeless. They are always valid.

Comment: As somebody who uses Visual Studio and is frequently hit with version specific bugs and all of the uh... flakiness that tends to go with Visual Studio being under heavy development, I'm with @Braiam; I would definitely prefer the version to be stripped out and just have the [visual-studio] tag instead unless it really is specific to just certain versions; IMO if it's in the latest version it should use [visual-studio], if it's not in the latest version you can add 2017 and/or 2019, 2021, etc.

Comment: @Braiam It depends on the technology. C# running on the .NET framework? Probably won't change much over the years. Visual Studio will completely revamp some of its interfaces with each new version (not always for the better), though. The extension system doesn't allow for targeting multiple VS versions, meaning some answers might be version specific. VS also adds new interfaces that supersede extensions sometimes, like adding the window for executing unit tests. The point being that not as many things are stable across versions of VS that would be in a programming language.

Comment: @jpmc26 typing in a box change between one version and the other? Did opening files? Did creating project? Copy-n-pasting? Creating unit test? No. They didn't change. New features were added, some cheese may be moved, but the questions are the same for all versions.

Comment: @Braiam Developers are highly unlikely to ask such basic questions. The things that actually change or are in some way complex or confusing, which are the most likely to get changed, are the most likely to get questions in the first place. And yes, unit tests do fall into that category. VS's "IntelliTest" was introduced in VS 2015, only 2 versions ago, for example. Running test frameworks other than MSTest also requires an extension or some special NuGet package (at least in 2017 and lower; I don't know if it changed in 2019), but I'd be surprised if it stays that way forever.

Comment: @Braiam yes but we aren't discussing "practical questions" we are literally talking about "buggy" ides and their "buggy" versions. if someone has a specific question about xamarin uitest as linked to vs2017 then someone telling them the issue was fixed in vs2019 isn't going to help them.

Comment: @jpmc26 another related example, there's [a particularly annoying bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071668/4975230) in MSTest in VS 2015 with x64 builds. Also I agree that "update to 20XX" isn't an answer all the time, personally I am stuck with VS 2015 due to third party support issues. Also, IMO bug workaround / explanation questions can be reasonable, answerable, and useful questions. Especially if there's zero chance of the bug being fixed.

Comment: @jpmc26 "Developers are highly unlikely to ask such basic questions" It doesn't matter. Questions are version independent. Answers not. Tags applies to questions, not to answers. I just put those as examples in such way that everyone, even your aunt, could understand the point. Apparently, it backfired.

Answer (score 7):

Do nothing.

Are you going to update it with VS2021, VS2023, VS2025, ... later on? What about all other questions tagged with specific version, where solution *works* in next one?

Version tag is very important on a borderline *before* that. For whatever after it *might* still work. If you want you can post comment *under answer* "works for VS2023", done.

You would be surprised by google search is *smart* to still show you that old popular VS2017 question even if you type `"c# stackoverflow where to create unit test vs 2023"`.

Comment: "Are you going to update it with VS2021, VS2023, VS2025, ... later on?" If it comes up and someone with the required knowledge sees it, yes. Questions and answers need to be maintained, anyway. What if an update invalidates the answer? Are you going to just not edit it? Changing information means changing the post. I recently updated [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006432/1394393) that kept accumulating upvotes because it had changed with new versions. That's what you're supposed to do.

Comment: @jpmc26 that's the way I've always looked at it. If I answer a question I try to be responsible for keeping that answer up to date whilst I still have up to date knowledge in that area

Comment: Comments are not permanent. Some kind of edit to an answer would be more appropriate for updated information regarding versioning.

Comment: @jpmc26, *"What if an update invalidates the answer"* - the question is still tagged with previous version, it is still valid for that version, I don't see problem here. Rather ask a new question and tag it with newer version.

Comment: @Sinatr What I had in mind was something like a bug fix within the same major version (e.g., an update to VS 2017 fixing something) invalidating a workaround or making it unnecessary.

Answer (score -4):

If you're *sure* that the question and its answers both apply as written to VS 2019 too, I see no reason not to [be bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Be_bold)* and go with option #1.  If somebody (OP or anyone else) disagrees, they can always revert your edit, and *then* you should take it to meta to figure out a solution that's acceptable to everyone.

(Not that there's anything wrong with proactively seeking guidance from meta even before editing, like you did here.  But it's also OK to just make the edit if you believe it to be beneficial and uncontroversial.)

<sup>*) Yes, that's a Wikipedia guideline, not an SO-specific one, but the same general principles apply here as well.  SO is a Q&A site, but it's also a kind of a wiki too.  All content here is editable by design, and all edits can be safely reverted.</sup>

Comment: *[...] and then you should take it to meta to figure out a solution that's acceptable to everyone* I disagree, I see no point in **not** asking here first, like OP has done it with this post.